Flutter: unable to signin using a Google account

I am NOT using Firebase
I am still in early developer phase, so not even tried to publish at all on Play Store
My goal is to ask user to login to allow to upload photos to user's google drive.
This question is not duplicated due the fact that almost 100% of questions/answers are related to Firebase.

My code is the following.
Please note: I ask user to login to allow to upload photos to user's Google drive.
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
  ],
);

class AuthManager {
  static Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> signIn() async {
    try {
      final account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      log('account: ${account?.toString()}', name: 'AuthManager');
      return account;
    } catch (error) {
      log('signIn error:', name: 'AuthManager');
      log(error.toString(), name: 'AuthManager');
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<void> signOut() async {
    try {
      _googleSignIn.disconnect();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  static Future<bool> isSignedIn() async {
    return _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
  }
}

The error logged is

[AuthManager] signIn error:
[AuthManager] PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

I know that error number 10 is 'developer error', due to something misconfigured.
But what!!?!?
WHAT I HAVE ALREADY TRIED

I generated a key store for my app
My app is being signed in debug mode.
Nothing changes, same exception

I created a oauth client for my app using package name and sha1 read from the generated keystore

I do not know how will Goggle login connect my flutter app with this oauth credential

Nothing changes, same exception number 10



sign-in is authencation what you need is authorization.    You need the user to authorize your application to access their google dirve account.  signin only gives you profile, openid and email scopes

We found the only problem was to publish OAuth page.

There is absolutely no need to setup something in Firebase
There is no need to create and download json credentials
Simply prepare OAuth page for publishing

This 3rd step requires signing the app and building it for release
Having release apk + rightly signed + OAuth page published allowed our app's users to login with any Google Account properly

Implemented similar thing, you need to generate keystore. Follow this guide for detailed answer. I suggest you to follow Android Studio Key Generation Steps.

What is the relation between a keystore and a problem with signin?

We need SHA-1 key for setup in Cloud Console.

How my app know there is a project in cloud console? and viceversa !? Please, edit your answer with details

You need to set up an OAuth client in the API & Services section of the Google Cloud Console. For Android, add the SHA-1 and package ID. For iOS, add the bundle ID. Then, rename the downloaded file to GoogleService-Info.plist and place it inside the ios/Runner folder.

As per my question, already setup OAuth client. Added the package name and package sha1 rightly. I still have problem, both on release and debug build, but only on real device.

There are different SHA1 varients for release and debug. Check that

Try the following (ignore the steps that you have already done)

Open API & Services Credentials
Click on Create Credentials
Then in dropdown click on OAuth Client ID
Application Type: Android
Name: Whatever like Android Dev
Package name: com.yourpackagename
SHA-1 certificate fingerprint: your_key. To generate go to root/android folder and run ./gradlew signingReport
Click on create
Test


if you're sign-in without requesting from the Drive access, then use this
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(

scopes: <String>[
'email',
'profile',

For android make sure that you have added google-services.json to your app directory. Also, ensure this configured properly
dependencies {
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'


If you want to use the google_sign_in flutter plugin, the docs says you need to register your application and points to the firebase setup guide i.e. you need to use firebase with this plugin

Not true, not need for firebase at all
We fixe simply publishing oauth app .
